# CSS Nav Bar wrapping around

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to create my very own css menubar and I am learning a lot. Unfortunately I am stuck on this one piece and I can't figure out how to get around it. My menubar is to long so I use line breaks to wrap each menu element around but its not letting my menu to run across the menu bar. Can you tell me what I am missing here?

```
<div id="menucontainer">
<ol id="navlinks">
  <li><a href="#">COMPANY<br />OVERVIEW</a></li>    
  <li><a href="#">CLIENTS<br />TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ACCREDITATION<br />SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LEGAL<br />SUPPORT</a></li>
  <li>TRAINING</li>
  <li><a href="#">CONSULTING<br />SERVICES</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FREE<br />POLICY CENTER</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">IN THE NEWS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">STRATEGIC<br />PARTNERS</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
   /* We set the width and color of the background for a menu wrapper. */
   #menucontainer{width: 1021px; height: 61px; background-color:#0C318C; margin: auto; padding-top:5px;}

   /* We target the top of the order list and remove the list properties. */
   #navlinks li {display: inline; list-style: none;}

   /* This line sets the font style of the bullet menu */ 
   ol{font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Tinos', serif;line-height: 18px;} 

   /* We target the li items with and without a hyper link and color the font white. */ 
   li, li a {text-decoration: none; color: white;}
```

I put it up on JFiddle and you can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/L4sTB/

Thanks,
Frank G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/L4sTB/1/).

I have made changes to the following CSS rule.

```
#navlinks li {
    display: inline-block; /* to display the menu items as blocks in same line */
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center; /* center align the text within the block */
    width: 10%; /* set each block a width */
    vertical-align: middle; /* align the contents to middle vertically */
}
```

Comment: This does what I was looking for which was to pull everything to the side. On to the next step drop menus uggg... thanks!

Comment: Just so I understand as I am learning. Because you used the inline-block that tells css to push everything over and block this area out causing the menu to move outward is this correct? Thanks again!

Comment: @FrankG. I forgot to remove the line breaks `<br/>` in your HTML. You can do that also and the appearance will remain the same. Bigger text will wrap around automatically because of the `width` setting.

Comment: @FrankG. right a block of space equivalent to the width setting is assigned to the element and since we have the block as `inline-block` they remain side-by-side.

Comment: yes and no, http://jsfiddle.net/L4sTB/ I tried just to see the breaks removed and it appears that it does it for the ones that are long but the shorter ones shows them straight across. I guess I could force a shorter width but not sure what that would do to the longer nav items. Interesting tho. Thank you!

Comment: @FrankG. I set the width as 10% because you have nine menu items (9*10) and the remaining 10% can be for the margin on left and right :) What I meant by wrap around was that if there is a chance of the value increasing in length, the code will automatically deal with it. You will have to change only the height of your container.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `display:inline-block` to your `li` elements and it will span the width of your nav bar: http://jsfiddle.net/shaunp/L4sTB/3/

Is this your desired effect?

Comment: Both work I like this but it might be a little confusing to a visitor because of all the links plus my next goal is to create a drop down menu for a few of these items. But before I get there I wanted to layout the navbar first. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The list should be `inline-block`. I added center align text and a border to each.

```
#navlinks li {display: inline-block; list-style: none;text-align:center;border: 1px solid white;}
```

Comment: The borders are helpful to see how an inline-block works. So it blocks the area not allowing anything around it causing the bar to move outward. Thank you!!!